# Secure message transportation

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, hmac, secret-sharing

1. It is secure to use the shared secret as the key for a HMAC? is it better to derive one key for all of the messages that are going to be HMACed or a key for each message?
2. Is it safe to use the shared secret as the key for the symmetric encryption after the shared secret has been exchanged using PKI?

Thanks.

Comment: It's always better not to repeat any key, once used

Comment: Since you have two questions, I'm not sure if these two are related. Will you encrypt and authenticate/sign (HMAC) each message or just use HMAC on plaintext without encryption?

Comment: I will encrypt and HMAC each message

Answer (score 0):

> It is secure to use the shared secret as the key for a HMAC? is it
>   better to derive one key for all of the messages that are going to be
>   HMACed or a key for each message?

As long as you use the key solely for HMAC, you can use single key for multiple messages [safely](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/how-many-times-can-a-key-be-used-for-hmac-sha256-before-it-needs-to-be-rotated). Many authentication protocols that issue tokens use one key for signing multiple tokens. [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/) is one such example. [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) has it's own implementation.

But please note that in case you need to encrypt and then HMAC the message, you need to use [two different keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37880/why-cant-i-use-the-same-key-for-encryption-and-mac). It is possible to derive these two out of a single, shared master key. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34700/deriving-aes-key-and-hmac-key-from-shorter-master-key) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13232/how-is-hkdf-expand-better-than-a-simple-hash).

There is a better approach though. You can use [GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-is-the-difference-between-cbc-and-gcm-mode) mode for encryption which will do exactly what you need with a [single](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44526/why-does-aes-gcm-not-require-an-auth-key-but-encrypt-then-mac-does) shared key. Make sure you use it properly, especially concerning the [IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42411/how-to-choose-the-size-of-the-iv-in-aes-gcm). Study it's [disadvantages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/practical-disadvantages-of-gcm-mode-encryption) too and see if they concern you.

> Is it safe to use the shared secret as the key for the symmetric
>   encryption after the shared secret has been exchanged using PKI?

Yes, this is an approach used in [SSL/TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) for example.